# viewing PHP file is restricted by IP (My IP), is there a way someone else to view it?

Tags: php, ip

I have website and have one page for receiving some news (newly registered users, activity, etc.) and is restricted for everyone except for my IP (Page for only me to view).

I'm interested if there is a way that someone else can "fake" my IP and view this file?

P.S. I am aware of other ways of doing this.

Comment: Faking / spoofing an ip means the response doesn't go back to the attacker so that would be pretty useless :-)

Comment: How are you getting the client's ip because there are some caveats (i.e. proxy ips)?

Comment: Are you on the Internet or Intranet? How do you connect to the server? It depends on your IP. Some tools are able to change IP address.

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], I don't mind proxy, I only want this file to be viewed my my IP only, and denied to other.

Comment: Ok as long as you are only using `REMOTE_ADDR` *and* are not behind a shared proxy / ip you should be just fine.

Comment: Thanks, Just becoming paranoid about everything :)

Comment: It's not paranoia if they are really after you.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/381393/can-the-ip-address-for-an-http-request-be-spoofed

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you dont get fixed IPs, most provider give dynamic IPs. So if you restart your Router, your IP will change and make it impossible to access the page again. If you get a fixed IP, it should work. He can ofc. modify the IP, but then he wont get the response back.

Comment: Most providers over here have such insane lease times you effectively have a static ip.

Comment: Really? Okay, didnt know that. If i restart my router, my IP immediatly changes.

Comment: Yes really. And it has been that way over here since I got rid of my dail-up modem.

Comment: This is not answer to the question.

Comment: \\_/ and this is the care cup. Its empty.

Answer (score -2):

<sub><sub>Converting my comments to an answer.</sub></sub>

It depends on how you are trying to get the client's IP address. If you are:

- only using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the ip address
- don't have a shared ip address
- don't use a (shared) proxy

You should be just fine, because a possible attacker *can* technically spoof the ip address, but that would not work because, (as [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573139/viewing-php-file-is-restricted-by-ip-my-ip-is-there-a-way-someone-else-to-vie/21573704?noredirect=1#comment32587142_21573704)) rightfully pointed out to me the tcp handshake would simply fail.

Some caveats:

- Your IP may change at some point effectively locking yourself out.
- When you are behind a proxy / internal -> external router / vpn / otherwise shared ip other people in the same network might also have access
- Never ever ever use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR ']` because this *can* be spoofed easily.

Comment: Not just response - TCP handshake will never succeed, so HTTP request will not even get through.